# DotNet CLI publish command to include packages from other NuGet source

Tags: teamcity, asp.net-core-2.0, dotnet-publish

For one of my .Net Core project, I have a BuldProject.cmd CLI which publish the project. CLI Command I used is this

```
dotnet publish --framework %DotNetCoreVersionToTarget% --configuration %ConfigurationModeToUse% --force --verbosity normal
```

Above command build the project fine using Teamcity build server.

Recently I added a DLL to my project not from

> nuget.org

but from my some other source say

> nuget.mypack.com/nuget

**csproj** file has an entry for new DLL

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="TestCoreAPI" Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now when I deploy the project using TeamCity I get the following error

```
 error NU1101: Unable to find package TestCoreAPI. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

The problem I see, it always looks into nuget.org for packages.
How can I modify my BuldProject.cmd CLI to look for other NuGet sources as well?

Comment: check this link out... not sure if it is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938270/netstandard-multi-targeting-library-packages-do-not-get-restored-when-building[1]