# .NETStandard multi-targeting library packages do not get restored when building

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, .net-standard, multitargeting

### Background:

I have created a multi-targeting library that targets `net40`, `net462`, and `netstandard2.0`. The purpose of this library is to wrap `StackExchange.Redis` and some related reconnect logic. For `net40` I need to use an older version of the package than the newer targets. Here is my `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net40;net462;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis">
      <Version>2.0.513</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis">
      <Version>2.0.513</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40'">
    <PackageReference Include="StackExchange.Redis.StrongName">
      <Version>1.1.608</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Generally this library seems to work and can be consumed by applications on the different target frameworks.

---

### Problem:

The problem I have now is trying to restore nuget packages for this project.

- When I build in Visual Studio,

  - I get several instances of this error coming from projects that
    indirectly reference my multi-targeting project:

    *The build restored NuGet packages. Build the project again to include these packages in the build. For more information, see [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568._)*
  - I also get many more instances of this error, from various projects that directly or indirectly reference my multi-targeting library. The `{Identifier}` and `{Namespace}` vary, some refer to entities in my multi-targeting library, some refer to entities in projects that depend on that.

    CS0234 *The type or namespace name '{Identifier}' does not exist in the namespace '{Namespace}' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*
  - If I build a second time, as the first error suggests, I get the same errors.
- If I right-click the solution in the *Solution Explorer* and choose
  *Restore Nuget Packages* after building, it does nothing and says: *All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.*
- If I choose *Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console*
  and enter the command `dotnet restore` then the build will work without error.

This project is the only one in the solution that uses multi-targeting and the csproj `<PackageReference>` package reference format.

I need restoring packages to be integrated into my build so that

- I don't need to explain to my coworkers how to work-around using the
  *Package Manager Console*.
- I can build this solution using third-party tools like TeamCity without requiring additional setup.

---

### Failed attempts:

Here are a few things I have tried so far:

- Added `dotnet restore` as a project pre-build event. This doesn't do anything.
- Used the *Visual Studio Solution Build Events* extension to run `dotnet restore` as a solution pre-build event. This works locally, but that extension is generally kind of unreliable and it won't help with third-party builds like TeamCity.
- Update the csproj file to use the older package reference format with a `packages.config` file. This introduced a lot of new build errors.

---

### Updates

- From the command line I get hundreds of CS0246 (*The type of namespace name 'Foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*)  and CS0234 errors, some even referring to types in base class libraries like System.Net. Using the `-restore` switch doesn't seem to change that. I may be overlooking something due to the amount of output there.
- Here is a minimal example that shows similar behavior https://github.com/JamesFaix/RestoreFailExample
  It generates a single CS0246 error, which is a little different. It also still fails when I try `dotnet restore` in the package manager console.
- I am using VS 15.9.9

---

I tried @Martin Ulrich's solution. This seemed to not work without also updating the references in my `csproj` files and removing `package.config` files. For this I used Visual Studio's built in conversion from the old format to the PackageReference format.

This changes my errors up a bit. The example repo I posted is probably not complex enough. I'm now getting a lot of

*Could not locate {project folder}\packages.config.  Ensure that this project has Microsoft.Bcl.Build installed and packages.config is located next to the project file.*,

a few

*This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {path to project}\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets.*

and a few `CS0246` errors like I was getting before.

The `CS0234` errors are gone now.

Comment: What do you mean by "not restored"? how did you check? (`obj\project.assets.json` file should be generated), is there a build error when not running the restore manually?

Comment: @MartinUllrich Updated "Problem" section with more error message details

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: Hi, what's the result if you build the project in command-line?(Add the -restore switch in the command) And it could be better if you can share a Minimal Reproducible sample(please delete all core code and personal data in it).

Comment: @Baruch VS 15.9.9

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT see updates at end of post

Comment: Sorry, it's published now

Comment: @JamesFaix Thanks for the reproducible one. I will check it later and reply with update as soon as possible.

Comment: @JamesFaix Are you sure VS15 support `netstandard`?

Comment: Yes (VS15 = VS2017). I also have the .NET Core module installed. Release date is March 2019 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes

Comment: Same issue seems to be not reproducible in my machine with your sample, as you said above, it only generates a CS0246. For this, according to your sample, there exists reference conflicts in your sample when targeting v4.0. Same situation for your complex solution?

Comment: Any update for this issue? The `Could not locate...` error seems to be an issue with BCL package, try [this workaround](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2913#issuecomment-239181431) to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing a PackageReference based project from a classic csproj file.

This, by default, means you need to manually install nuget packages to the classic project, as it is not using the transitive behavior of PackageReference.

To work around this issue, you can add the following to the `<PropertyGroup>` of your classic csproj file:

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```